# Rails app crashing in heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I've been all over today trying to figure out why my rails app is crashing on heroku.

Here's the output from heroku log:

```
2012-09-06T01:33:43+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2012-09-06T01:33:43+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
2012-09-06T01:33:43+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:1:in `new'
2012-09-06T01:33:43+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
2012-09-06T01:33:43+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
2012-09-06T01:33:43+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2012-09-06T01:33:43+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
2012-09-06T01:33:43+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:301:in `wrapped_app'
2012-09-06T01:33:43+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:252:in `start'
2012-09-06T01:33:43+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
2012-09-06T01:33:43+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
2012-09-06T01:33:43+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
2012-09-06T01:33:43+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
2012-09-06T01:33:43+00:00 app[web.1]:   from script/rails:6:in `require'
2012-09-06T01:33:43+00:00 app[web.1]:   from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
2012-09-06T01:33:44+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2012-09-06T01:33:44+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2012-09-06T01:33:46+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET whispering-atoll-2029.herokuapp.com/ dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
2012-09-06T01:33:46+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET whispering-atoll-2029.herokuapp.com/favicon.ico dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
2012-09-06T01:41:17+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation started
2012-09-06T01:41:49+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v10 created by jared@xoorath.com
2012-09-06T01:41:49+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 1c4a107 by jared@xoorath.com
2012-09-06T01:41:49+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2012-09-06T01:41:50+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished
2012-09-06T01:41:55+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server -p 51538`
2012-09-06T01:42:11+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2012-09-06T01:42:11+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2012-09-06T01:42:11+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2012-09-06T01:42:14+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2012-09-06T01:42:14+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.2.8 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:51538
2012-09-06T01:42:14+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2012-09-06T01:42:14+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
2012-09-06T01:42:14+00:00 app[web.1]: Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
2012-09-06T01:42:14+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2012-09-06T01:42:14+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.0/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:147:in `block in replace_gem': Please install the postgresql adapter: `gem install activerecord-postgresql-adapter` (pg is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.) (LoadError)
2012-09-06T01:42:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
2012-09-06T01:42:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2012-09-06T01:42:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
2012-09-06T01:42:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
2012-09-06T01:42:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2012-09-06T01:42:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:50:in `resolve_hash_connection'
2012-09-06T01:42:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:41:in `resolve_string_connection'
2012-09-06T01:42:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:27:in `spec'
2012-09-06T01:42:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:129:in `establish_connection'
2012-09-06T01:42:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
2012-09-06T01:42:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
2012-09-06T01:42:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
2012-09-06T01:42:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `block in run_load_hooks'
2012-09-06T01:42:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `run_load_hooks'
2012-09-06T01:42:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `each'
2012-09-06T01:42:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/base.rb:721:in `<top (required)>'
2012-09-06T01:42:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/devise-2.1.2/lib/devise/orm/active_record.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
2012-09-06T01:42:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2012-09-06T01:42:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
2012-09-06T01:42:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
2012-09-06T01:42:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2012-09-06T01:42:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/initializers/devise.rb:16:in `block in <top (required)>'
2012-09-06T01:42:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/initializers/devise.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
2012-09-06T01:42:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/devise-2.1.2/lib/devise.rb:247:in `setup'
2012-09-06T01:42:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
2012-09-06T01:42:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `block in load'
2012-09-06T01:42:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
2012-09-06T01:42:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
2012-09-06T01:42:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:588:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
2012-09-06T01:42:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:587:in `each'
2012-09-06T01:42:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:587:in `block in <class:Engine>'
2012-09-06T01:42:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2012-09-06T01:42:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2012-09-06T01:42:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
2012-09-06T01:42:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2012-09-06T01:42:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2012-09-06T01:42:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
2012-09-06T01:42:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2012-09-06T01:42:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2012-09-06T01:42:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2012-09-06T01:42:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
2012-09-06T01:42:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
2012-09-06T01:42:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
2012-09-06T01:42:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2012-09-06T01:42:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2012-09-06T01:42:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2012-09-06T01:42:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
2012-09-06T01:42:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
2012-09-06T01:42:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:1:in `new'
2012-09-06T01:42:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2012-09-06T01:42:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
2012-09-06T01:42:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:252:in `start'
2012-09-06T01:42:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
2012-09-06T01:42:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:301:in `wrapped_app'
2012-09-06T01:42:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
2012-09-06T01:42:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
2012-09-06T01:42:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
2012-09-06T01:42:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
2012-09-06T01:42:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   from script/rails:6:in `require'
2012-09-06T01:42:14+00:00 app[web.1]:   from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
2012-09-06T01:42:16+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2012-09-06T01:42:16+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2012-09-06T01:42:17+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET whispering-atoll-2029.herokuapp.com/ dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
2012-09-06T01:42:17+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET whispering-atoll-2029.herokuapp.com/favicon.ico dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
2012-09-06T01:42:19+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET whispering-atoll-2029.herokuapp.com/ dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
2012-09-06T01:42:19+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET whispering-atoll-2029.herokuapp.com/favicon.ico dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Here's my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '3.2.8'

#gem 'thin', '1.2.8'
gem 'devise'
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
end
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem "compass-rails", ">= 1.0.3", :group => :assets
gem "zurb-foundation", ">= 3.0.9", :group => :assets
gem "simple_form", ">= 2.0.2"
```

Here is my [repo](http://github.com/xoorath/TimeTracker)

I'm using devise, foundation.zurb, and a few other things. This is my first rails app, so maybe there is some important info I'm forgetting to tell you guys. Any help is greatly appreciated! Note that I've been changing things left right and center to try and get this fixed, so note that my gemfile from pastie is not the same as the one in the repo. The one I pasted here is the one I'm trying to use.

Let me know if there is any more information I can provide.

Update::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

I've changed my gemfile like so:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '3.2.8'

#gem 'thin', '1.2.8'
gem 'devise'
group :production do
    gem 'pg'
end
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem "compass-rails", ">= 1.0.3", :group => :assets
gem "zurb-foundation", ">= 3.0.9", :group => :assets
gem "simple_form", ">= 2.0.2"
```

and now it's not crashing, but I'm hitting the 500.html file

Here's the heoku log:

```
2012-09-06T02:21:50+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
2012-09-06T02:21:50+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2012-09-06T02:21:50+00:00 app[web.1]: Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
2012-09-06T02:21:52+00:00 app[web.1]: Hello World[2012-09-06 02:21:52] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2012-09-06T02:21:52+00:00 app[web.1]: [2012-09-06 02:21:52] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2 port=14673
2012-09-06T02:21:52+00:00 app[web.1]: [2012-09-06 02:21:52] INFO  ruby 1.9.2 (2011-07-09) [x86_64-linux]
2012-09-06T02:21:53+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2012-09-06T02:21:55+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R12 (Exit timeout) -> At least one process failed to exit within 10 seconds of SIGTERM
2012-09-06T02:21:55+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping remaining processes with SIGKILL
2012-09-06T02:21:57+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2012-09-06T02:22:00+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-09-06T02:22:00+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-09-06T02:22:00+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 74.14.32.8 at 2012-09-06 02:22:00 +0000
2012-09-06T02:22:00+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
2012-09-06T02:22:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (12.3ms)
2012-09-06T02:22:00+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 147ms
2012-09-06T02:22:00+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-09-06T02:22:00+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (File to import not found or unreadable: foundation/common/ratios.
2012-09-06T02:22:00+00:00 app[web.1]:     6:     <title>Timetracker</title>
2012-09-06T02:22:00+00:00 app[web.1]:     7:     <meta name="description" content=""/>
2012-09-06T02:22:00+00:00 app[web.1]: Load path: /app
2012-09-06T02:22:00+00:00 app[web.1]:     9:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
2012-09-06T02:22:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   (in /app/app/assets/stylesheets/foundation_and_overrides.scss)):
2012-09-06T02:22:00+00:00 app[web.1]:     10:     <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
2012-09-06T02:22:00+00:00 app[web.1]:     8:     <meta name="author" content=""/>
2012-09-06T02:22:00+00:00 app[web.1]:     11:     <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
2012-09-06T02:22:00+00:00 app[web.1]:     12:     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
2012-09-06T02:22:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/assets/stylesheets/foundation_and_overrides.scss:1
2012-09-06T02:22:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:9:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__3480637122833364973_39068600'
2012-09-06T02:22:00+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-09-06T02:22:00+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-09-06T02:22:00+00:00 heroku[router]: GET whispering-atoll-2029.herokuapp.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=275ms status=500 bytes=643
2012-09-06T02:22:00+00:00 heroku[router]: GET whispering-atoll-2029.herokuapp.com/favicon.ico dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=12ms status=200 bytes=1150
2012-09-06T02:22:02+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-09-06T02:22:02+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-09-06T02:22:02+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 74.14.32.8 at 2012-09-06 02:22:02 +0000
2012-09-06T02:22:02+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
2012-09-06T02:22:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (0.0ms)
2012-09-06T02:22:02+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 8ms
2012-09-06T02:22:02+00:00 app[web.1]: Load path: /app
2012-09-06T02:22:02+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-09-06T02:22:02+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (File to import not found or unreadable: foundation/common/ratios.
2012-09-06T02:22:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   (in /app/app/assets/stylesheets/foundation_and_overrides.scss)):
2012-09-06T02:22:02+00:00 app[web.1]:     7:     <meta name="description" content=""/>
2012-09-06T02:22:02+00:00 app[web.1]:     6:     <title>Timetracker</title>
2012-09-06T02:22:02+00:00 app[web.1]:     10:     <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
2012-09-06T02:22:02+00:00 app[web.1]:     8:     <meta name="author" content=""/>
2012-09-06T02:22:02+00:00 app[web.1]:     9:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
2012-09-06T02:22:02+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-09-06T02:22:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/assets/stylesheets/foundation_and_overrides.scss:1
2012-09-06T02:22:02+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:9:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__3480637122833364973_39068600'
2012-09-06T02:22:02+00:00 app[web.1]:     11:     <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
2012-09-06T02:22:02+00:00 app[web.1]:     12:     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
2012-09-06T02:22:02+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-09-06T02:22:02+00:00 heroku[router]: GET whispering-atoll-2029.herokuapp.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=43ms status=500 bytes=643
2012-09-06T02:22:03+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-09-06T02:22:03+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 74.14.32.8 at 2012-09-06 02:22:03 +0000
2012-09-06T02:22:03+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-09-06T02:22:03+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
2012-09-06T02:22:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (0.0ms)
2012-09-06T02:22:03+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 9ms
2012-09-06T02:22:03+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-09-06T02:22:03+00:00 app[web.1]:     8:     <meta name="author" content=""/>
2012-09-06T02:22:03+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (File to import not found or unreadable: foundation/common/ratios.
2012-09-06T02:22:03+00:00 app[web.1]:     10:     <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
2012-09-06T02:22:03+00:00 app[web.1]: Load path: /app
2012-09-06T02:22:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   (in /app/app/assets/stylesheets/foundation_and_overrides.scss)):
2012-09-06T02:22:03+00:00 app[web.1]:     6:     <title>Timetracker</title>
2012-09-06T02:22:03+00:00 app[web.1]:     7:     <meta name="description" content=""/>
2012-09-06T02:22:03+00:00 app[web.1]:     9:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
2012-09-06T02:22:03+00:00 app[web.1]:     11:     <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
2012-09-06T02:22:03+00:00 app[web.1]:     12:     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
2012-09-06T02:22:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:9:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__3480637122833364973_39068600'
2012-09-06T02:22:03+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/assets/stylesheets/foundation_and_overrides.scss:1
2012-09-06T02:22:03+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-09-06T02:22:03+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-09-06T02:22:03+00:00 heroku[router]: GET whispering-atoll-2029.herokuapp.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=32ms status=500 bytes=643
2012-09-06T02:22:03+00:00 heroku[router]: GET whispering-atoll-2029.herokuapp.com/favicon.ico dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=0
2012-09-06T02:22:06+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-09-06T02:22:06+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-09-06T02:22:06+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 74.14.32.8 at 2012-09-06 02:22:06 +0000
2012-09-06T02:22:06+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
2012-09-06T02:22:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (0.0ms)
2012-09-06T02:22:06+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 9ms
2012-09-06T02:22:06+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-09-06T02:22:06+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (File to import not found or unreadable: foundation/common/ratios.
2012-09-06T02:22:06+00:00 app[web.1]: Load path: /app
2012-09-06T02:22:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   (in /app/app/assets/stylesheets/foundation_and_overrides.scss)):
2012-09-06T02:22:06+00:00 app[web.1]:     6:     <title>Timetracker</title>
2012-09-06T02:22:06+00:00 app[web.1]:     7:     <meta name="description" content=""/>
2012-09-06T02:22:06+00:00 app[web.1]:     8:     <meta name="author" content=""/>
2012-09-06T02:22:06+00:00 app[web.1]:     9:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
2012-09-06T02:22:06+00:00 app[web.1]:     10:     <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
2012-09-06T02:22:06+00:00 app[web.1]:     11:     <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
2012-09-06T02:22:06+00:00 app[web.1]:     12:     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
2012-09-06T02:22:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/assets/stylesheets/foundation_and_overrides.scss:1
2012-09-06T02:22:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:9:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__3480637122833364973_39068600'
2012-09-06T02:22:06+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-09-06T02:22:06+00:00 heroku[router]: GET whispering-atoll-2029.herokuapp.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=18ms status=500 bytes=643
2012-09-06T02:22:06+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-09-06T02:22:06+00:00 heroku[router]: GET whispering-atoll-2029.herokuapp.com/favicon.ico dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=6ms status=304 bytes=0
```

Comment: do you have rack-1.4.1 installed?  (run gem list in the command line)

Comment: Yeah, 1.4.1 is installed. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: I don't think you have do this in application.css.scss: `= require foundation_and_overrides`. It's already required by `= require_tree .`.

Comment: Post code directly here instead of linking to it. If the link ever dies then your question becomes useless to future visitors. You may also want to improve your title.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Reading from the logs:

> /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.0/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:147:in
>   `block in replace_gem': Please install the postgresql adapter:`gem
>   install activerecord-postgresql-adapter` (pg is not part of the
>   bundle. Add it to Gemfile.) (LoadError)

Heroku uses postgres to connect to the database (not sqlite), so add a production group including postgres gem

```
group :production do
    gem 'pg'
end
```

This tells bundler that on production, install the pg gem (which Heroku wants).

---

Update:

For your second problem. From the logs again:

> 2012-09-06T02:22:00+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error
>   (File to import not found or unreadable: foundation/common/ratios.
>   2012-09-06T02:22:00+00:00 app[web.1]:     6:
>   Timetracker 2012-09-06T02:22:00+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   7:      2012-09-06T02:22:00+00:00
>   app[web.1]: Load path: /app 2012-09-06T02:22:00+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   9:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
>   2012-09-06T02:22:00+00:00 app[web.1]:   (in
>   /app/app/assets/stylesheets/foundation_and_overrides.scss)):
>   2012-09-06T02:22:00+00:00 app[web.1]:     10:     <%=
>   javascript_include_tag "application" %> 2012-09-06T02:22:00+00:00
>   app[web.1]:     8:     
>   2012-09-06T02:22:00+00:00 app[web.1]:     11:     <%= csrf_meta_tags
>   %> 2012-09-06T02:22:00+00:00 app[web.1]:     12:     
>   2012-09-06T02:22:00+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   app/assets/stylesheets/foundation_and_overrides.scss:1
>   2012-09-06T02:22:00+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:9:in
>   `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__3480637122833364973_39068600'

That's the sass file: [foundation_and_overrides.scss](https://github.com/xoorath/TimeTracker/blob/master/app/assets/stylesheets/foundation_and_overrides.scss). First, the postfixes are not in [asset-pipeline form](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#how-to-use-the-asset-pipeline). Also, in that file, the imports refer to missing files.

**TL;DR: Spend some time to read the output logs!** Most things will complain there if it fails ;)

Comment: The problem is that /app/app/assets/stylesheets/foundation_and_overrides.scss cannot be found, I think.

Comment: You're right Mischa! Turns out I needed to run 'bundle exec rake assets:precompile'

Comment: So what's the etiquette for accepting an answer here? If either of you submit an answer that mentions the first issue of switching to pg followed by precompiling the assets, I'll give it a checkmark.

Comment: @Xoorath, I think you should accept Jeff's answer cause he answered your initial question correctly. You should have open a new question for a new problem, but ah well...